How can I define the inverse to Möbius gyrovector addition?
I know that Möbius gyrovector addition can be defined as:
$$\mathbf {w}= \mathbf {u} \oplus _{M}\mathbf {v} ={\frac {(1+{\frac {2}{s^{2}}}\mathbf {u} \cdot \mathbf {v} +{\frac {1}{s^{2}}}|\mathbf {v} |^{2})\mathbf {u} +(1-{\frac {1}{s^{2}}}|\mathbf {u} |^{2})\mathbf {v} }{1+{\frac {2}{s^{2}}}\mathbf {u} \cdot \mathbf {v} +{\frac {1}{s^{4}}}|\mathbf {u} |^{2}|\mathbf {v} |^{2}}},
$$
as given in the relevant Wikipedia entry.
In my case $s=1$ so it just simplifies to:
$$\mathbf {w}= \mathbf {u} \oplus _{M}\mathbf {v} ={\frac {(1+2(\mathbf {u} \cdot \mathbf {v}) +|\mathbf {v} |^{2})\mathbf {u} +(1-|\mathbf {u} |^{2})\mathbf {v} }{1+2(\mathbf {u} \cdot \mathbf {v}) +|\mathbf {u} |^{2}|\mathbf {v} |^{2}}},
$$
but how would I define the inverse vector
$\mathbf {u}= \mathbf {w} \ominus _{M}\mathbf {v}$?

I’m new to this, but I would guess to first find an identity element $\mathbf 0$ such that $\mathbf 0 \oplus_M \mathbf v=\mathbf v$, then find $\mathbf{-v}$ such that $\mathbf{-v}\oplus_M \mathbf v=\mathbf 0$
